# PK Contraint with insert in EF and Auto Increment field

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, auto-increment

I have had code running for about a week now and all of a sudden it is giving me an error on `db.saveContext()`. It is inserting into a table and the PK is an Identity field with auto increment enabled.

Now i am gettign an exception in code saying:
`{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Acks'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Acks'. The duplicate key value is (12685028).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

This seems really odd to me that it would all of a sudden become an issue.

here is my code:

```
  if (logBufferCounter++ > 1000)
            {
                logBufferCounter = 0;
                db.SaveChanges();
                recreateContext();
            }
```

I have also tried removing the 1000 batch update for debugging. And still the same error. I have also removed `recreateContext()` and still same error.

There is only one instance of this code running.

What could be the issue? It seems as if I have stumbled into some lower level error.

Here is how I create my object:

```
  Ack tableItem = new Ack();
        try
        {
            tableItem.messageId = logUtil.getMessageId(tmpPacket);
            tableItem.serverId = logItem.serverId;
            tableItem.time = logUtil.getTime(tmpPacket.getValueOfTag(tcp_packet.pck_tag_types.TM));
            int mr = Convert.ToInt32(tmpPacket.getValueOfTag(tcp_packet.pck_tag_types.MR));
            tableItem.direction = logUtil.getDirection(mr);
            tableItem.isNack = !tmpPacket.is_ack();
            tableItem.unitId = logUtil.getAckUnitId(tmpPacket);

            // Calculate The Client Id
            tcp_packet.pck_item cl;
            if (tmpPacket.find(tcp_packet.pck_tag_types.CL, out cl))
            {
                tableItem.clientId = cl.value;
            }
            else
            {
                tableItem.clientId = null;
            }             

            tableItem.data = tableItem.data.Substring(0, 50);


            // Save to db
            db.Acks.Add(tableItem);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Could not build tmpItem for an ack packet: " + logItem.payload, e);
        }
```

I am using EF 6.1 Databse First with sql server 2012.

What value should you initialize the auto increment key / value to?

[EDIT]
 Ack model class:

```
public partial class Ack
{
    public long ackId { get; set; }
    public long messageId { get; set; }
    public byte serverId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime time { get; set; }
    public bool direction { get; set; }
    public bool isNack { get; set; }
    public string unitId { get; set; }
    public string clientId { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }

    public virtual Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

|Here is the table in sql manager
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't initialize the PK to anything. If you are using Code-First fluent configuration and your primary key property is called Id or AckId then EF will assume that that property is your PK and that it is an auto-incrementing identity field. What property on your Ack object is the PK?

Comment: what is the mapping of Acks PrimaryKey ? what is sql definition of this mapping ? Aren't you triying to insert another object linked to an Ack object ?

Comment: I am using Database first. And I have checked in my edmx and that field does have the `storeGeneratedPattern=idenity`

Comment: @tschmit007 I am only inserting that ack object, nothing linking to it. It does however link to other tables.

Comment: what does `select ident_current('Acks'), max(ackId) from Acks` returns (in SSMS)?

Comment: @tschmit007 it returns null ?

Comment: it seems to mean that you do not have an identity constraint on your table... ??!! (are you sysadmin or at least dbowner on the connection used by SSMS)

Comment: |It is though, see my edit. Maybe I didnt execute the query correctly, do I no need to say FROM which table?

Comment: I infer that Acks was the table name, may be I'm wrong

Comment: Nope that is correct. however I ran that same query on my log table, which has the same setup and has same program writing to it. but it is working and it also returned null. Is there a possibility some where a insert got corrupt and has messed with the auto increment?

Comment: can you insert directly using SSMS ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, for some unexpected reason, the SEED of an IDENTITY column can get corrupted. As you say it's been working and you're getting errors lately, I suppose this is what have happened (unless you changed anything else!).

If so, you should try running this in your DB:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('SchemaName.TableName', NORESEED)
```

this will so the current seed (the next generated value is seed + 1)

If the next value exists in the DB you must change the seed using this command

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('SchemaName.TableName', RESEED)
```

For more info, see this: [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Im not sure but are the two Commands meant to be the same?

Comment: oops, it was a typo. The second instance should had been RESEED instead of NORESSED. Edited!

Comment: Thought so, Thanks for the edit. Much appreciated. Will try it out today and let you know.

Comment: Ok so i just ran your test, The first command return me a value of `12685029` and i did a select from the table and it found an entry with that value. So it appears to be corrupt. However after running the second command, i get the same value back? So the reseed doesnt seem to change anything? however if I look in my table there is OK with the value of `12685095` which is much bigger than the suggested seed value?

Comment: If you have a SEED with value 12685029, the next inserted value will be 12685030 (providede it has the default increment of 1). The collision would happen in that number. If the table has a value of 12685095, obviously there are values inserted with a PK bigger than the identity seed. So you need to run the RESEED command. When you run it the seed will become 12685095, (provided this is the max existing id) so that the next inserted value is 12685096. I recommended to run the NORESEED to check that there is a problem, and then RESEED to solve it, in case there is a problem.

Comment: I did run reseed on it, and it didn't change anything? It kept the Identity Value the same? Strangely as here are bigger entries. I just truncated the table, and reseeded. luckily the db is still in development . but I would hate for this to happen on live db. What causes / can be done to prevent a corrupt seed?

Comment: It's really, really strange. I've never found that problem or heard that someone has found it, apart from you ;) Hopefully you'll never get that error again. There is a third CHECKIDENT syntax that allows to manually specify the new seed value (see the docs), so you didn't have to truncate the table. You should run DBCC CHECKDB to check your DB integrity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx This doesn't look fine at all.

Comment: I think I could have found the source of the problem, well maybe. See my other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500591/ef-performing-a-select-on-every-insert-with-identity-coloumn/25501374#25501374

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with your problem. In fact it confirms that that identity can't cause problems: "This never causes race conditions, because an identity column is always incremented when an insert happens (it never rolls back) and scope_identity() always returns the identity value that's generated within the scope of the INSERT statement", which is 100% correct. You cannot insert a value by hand in an identity columns, unless you run SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx Forget it, I bet it will not happen again, seriously.